# In Angular2 how do you change a sidebar based on the active route?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I'm writing an SPA using Angular 2 (RC5) and Typescript.  I have a main navbar on top (using Bootstrap 4 Alpha 3), and a custom-designed sidebar.  Here's a pic:

[image]

The intention here is to navigate to a main "application" using the top navbar.  Currently I have 3 main apps mapped out - Tracker, Proboard and Equipment.  Once a main application has been activated, the links on the sidebar would change.  In the picture above, the sidebar is showing links for the 'Proboard' application.

How can I change the contents of the sidebar based on the active route without having a bunch of '*ngIf' declarations in my HTML?

I would like to have a JSON object in my code somewhere (perhaps retrieved from a backend API) that would list the links for each app.  Something like:

```
[
  { proboard: [
    { label: 'Home', link: '/proboard', icon: 'fa-home'},
    { label: 'Candidates', link: '/proboard/candidates', icon: 'fa-users'},
    { label: 'New', link: '/proboard/candidate/new', icon: 'fa-new-user; } ]
  },
  { tracker: [...] },
  { equipment: [...] }
]
```

Then when the user would navigate to one of the links on the top navbar, the sidebar would be populated with the contents in the array above, using an `NgFor` in the HTML.

Any suggestions or links would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done the same thing and here is how I solved it.

1. Created the menu in the top-most app component
2. Created a service and kept a common routing table in the service
3. Created a subscribable subject stream for changing the route
4. Subscribed to that stream from the component where the menu resides
5. Issue subcription.next from the current component which sets the selected route in the component with the menu.

You can achieve this with other type of component interactions. Here is more info on that from the Angular 2 docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: When you say 'subscribable subject stream' you're talking about an observable, right?  I can totally see how this would work, but it feels like a bit overkill.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about an observable subject stream. There is more than one way to do this of course. It's the cleanest way I can think of, it might be overkill for what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is more or less how I actually accomplished this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution.

Since each of your three apps is meant to be completely separate (as you've defined it), you could make a completely independent 'SideBarComponent' that you can reuse in each app.

Since you can give a component any information you want with @Input() variables, you can provide it the list of labels, links, and icons it needs. For example:

EquipmentComponent.ts

```
sideBarLinks: any = { proboard: [
  { label: 'Home', link: '/proboard', icon: 'fa-home'},
  { label: 'Candidates', link: '/proboard/candidates', icon: 'fa-users'},
  { label: 'New', link: '/proboard/candidate/new', icon: 'fa-new-user; } ]
}
```

EquipmentComponent.html

```
<side-bar [buttons]='sideBarLinks'></side-bar>
```

SideBarComponent.ts

```
@Input()
buttons: any;
```

SideBarComponent.html

```
// Use 'buttons' to construct your buttons in the sidebar. Possibly using an ng repeater in this template.
```

Even if you don't end up implementing this exactly, I hope this gets you thinking in the direction of using reusable components with Angular 2.

Hopefully this is helpful!

Here's more than everything you would need to know about component interactions: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html.

Comment: This is a great suggestion, and it fits my way of thinking about such things.  Although I'm not new to programming, I'm new to web programming and Angular2 in particular, so this definitely did get me thinking about reusability.

Comment: Ah, I feel that. I switched from game to web programming and had the same sort of adventure :P 

Here's some REALLY good resources on how to make your Angular code reusable (they were written for Angular 1.x.x, but was recommended by the Angular team in order to transition to 2, so same design ideas)

https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/component-based-angularjs-directives
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMkd0nYmLzY

http://teropa.info/blog/2014/10/24/how-ive-improved-my-angular-apps-by-banning-ng-controller.html

The video in that last link is especially awesome.

Answer (score 1):

**2 possible ways**

1 - In sidebar component, subscribe to router changes, but you will end up using `*ngIf`

```
@Input()
data: any;

constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.changes.subscribe((val) => {
        if(val === 'noSidebarRoute'){
            this.navButtons= false;
        }
        else {
            this.navButtons= navData;
        }
    })
}
```

then in parent component template

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `<side-bar [data]='navData'></side-bar>`
});

export class Parent{

navData = [
     { proboard: [
       { label: 'Home', link: '/proboard', icon: 'fa-home'},
       { label: 'Candidates', link: '/proboard/candidates', icon: 'fa-users'},
       { label: 'New', link: '/proboard/candidate/new', icon: 'fa-new-user; }
     ]},
     { tracker: [...] },
     { equipment: [...] }
]}
```

2 - in your app component (or sidebar parent component), use `resolver.resolveComponent` to dynamically add the sidebar component to your app, this way you won't be using data binding (`*ngIf`).

```
sidebarCmpRef:ComponentRef<any>;

constructor(private router: Router,
            private viewContainerRef:ViewContainerRef,
            private resolver:ComponentResolver) {

    router.changes.subscribe((val) => {
        if(val === 'noSidebarRoute'){
            if(this.sidebarCmpRef){
               this.sidebarCmpRef.destroy();
               this.sidebarCmpRef
            }
        }
        else{
            this.AddSidebar();
        }
    })
}

AddSidebar(){
    if(!this.cmpRef){
        this.resolver.resolveComponent(<Type>SideBar)
          .then((factory:ComponentFactory<any>) => {
            this.cmpRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
            this.cmpRef.instance.buttons= navData;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  In #1, is `val` going to be the active route?  I onder if instead of doing `this.show = false` or `this.show = true` I can do something like `this.linkDescriptions = desc` where `desc` is an element from the JSON array I mentioned in the OP?

Comment: Is there `changes` property on `router` indeed? I don't see it in the reference.

Comment: @JohnDibling yes you can

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to go with angular basic approach i.e loading children inside the routes.

Define your main.route as follows

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './shared/components/pagenotfound.component';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tracker',
    loadChildren: 'app/tracker/module#trackermodule',
  },
  {
    path: 'proboard',
    loadChildren: 'app/proboard/module#proboard',
  },
 {
    path: 'equiment',
    loadChildren: 'app/equiment/module#equiment',
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
    declarations: [
        PageNotFoundComponent
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRouterModule {
}
```

then in your child/sub-module routing configuration should be

```
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {  CssComponent } from './view';
import { RadioAndCheckBoxComponent } from './radio-and-checkbox/view';

export const RouteComponents = [
  CssComponent
];

export const Routes = RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: '',
    component: equimentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'Home',
        component: HomeComoponent
      },
      {
        path: 'Candidates',
        component: CandidatesComoponent
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same situation (Main Menu Links and their respected sub menu items), I have done this in following manner.

Inside the root component (app.component.ts) constructor, I subscribe to router events, and based on the redirect route URL, I hide and show the Main application sub menus. Here is code:

```
 this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {

    this.currentUrl = event.urlAfterRedirects;
    console.log(event.urlAfterRedirects);

    if (this.currentUrl.includes("/MainMenuLink1")) {
      this.link1SubMenu = true;
      this.link2SubMenu = false;
    } else if (this.currentUrl.includes("/MainMenuLink2")) {
   this.link2SubMenu = true;
      this.link1SubMenu = false;
    }

  }
});
```

And based on that [link1SubMenu] boolean values, I show and hide the Sub menu in app.component.html using *ngIf='link1SubMenu'

It needs to be refactored, but this is quick win.